# Amazon EC2: possible to use elastic load balancing across web servers in multiple regions based on location of client?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Related to an [another question I asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/248751/amazon-ec2-how-would-i-configure-ec2-for-a-global-public-web-app).  [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/132043/amazon-cloudfront-and-ec2-global-load-balancing) seems similar but I'm wondering if there are any updates.

To support a single site that has users all over the world, I will create EC2 web servers in the US, Asia and Europe regions.  The web server instances in the US and Asia regions will be backed by RDS replicas. Is it possible to load balance across these three regions? So when a customer from Spain goes to example.com, she should be routed to the EC2 instances in Europe region, a customer in Miami should be sent to the instance in Eastern US region, etc.  Is this possible to do this with just AWS features?  Are there docs on how to set this up?

Answer (score 5):

Check out Amazon Route 53

http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2010/12/dns_amazon_route_53.html

> Route 53 is designed to be fast, easy to use, and cost-effective. It
>   answers DNS queries with low latency by using a global network of DNS
>   servers. Queries for your domain are automatically routed to the
>   nearest DNS server, and thus answered with the best possible
>   performance.

http://aws.amazon.com/route53/

Comment: Route 53 does not support GSLB, yet. They are talking about it.  However, changing your DNS is your "last line of defense" if AWS goes down completely, so using Amazon for that too is probably unwise.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is very old thread (2011) but I came across this in early 2015, so might someone else, hence clarifying that as of 2015, Amazon route 53 does indeed support GeoLocation based routing :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo

Answer (score 1):

[Zerigo offer GeoIP services](http://www.zerigo.com/news/launch-of-geodns-geolocation-load-balancing) seems cheap at about $20 a month. i use them for managing about 40 domains, but none of the GeoIP yet... there is another place called [EdgeLocator](http://edgedirector.com/) who charge per million DNS requests. seems to be a PAYG service... have not used them, but you might want to check them out for testing...

Comment: Zerigo doesn't appear to be using anycast, which means users probably won't be answered by the nearest DNS server.

Comment: in theory, your DNS should be provided by your ISP though, so you wont go direct, your ISP will... you should get results from them. but, yes, i can see it being a bit of a slow down...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Amazon CloudFront?

Comment: Cloudfront is for static assets.  I don't think it can't serve example.com/home.php.

Comment: you can to an extent. I ran my blog on wordpress behind a cloudfront distribution for a while... It worked, but it was not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not possible using built in AWS features.  You'd need to get GSLB from a provider like [Dynect](http://www.dynect.com)

Answer (score -1):

use geo-ip routing, one provider here: http://www.maxmind.com/app/country

http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/mod_geoip2/mod_geoip2_1.2.5.tar.gz 
doesn't sound like a tough deal,but keeping up todate mapping info might be tougher.

and effectively trivial,if ... we can do..

## Redirect one country

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^FR$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fr.mybosses-dom.com $1 [NC,301,L]

and then redirect them to WWW.YOURDOMAIN.JP,(in japan (or singapore,or someplace close),
or to WWW.YOURDOM.COM, or WWW.YOUDOM.DE,etc.

we are in the midst of doing this ourselves.

Also see:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#archive-access-multiplexer

Comment: This describes the process for Apache, the OP wanted to know for ELB